# TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 4 found

Tags: python

I got an error as stated in the title that I didn't get when I first compiled it.  I gave up trying to fix it myself so I had to ask for help online since I had wasted too much time fixing it myself.

```
letters = ["bean"]

numbers = []
number = 0
for letter in letters:
    number = ord(letter) - 96
    numbers.append(number)
print(numbers)
```

Comment: Change first line to `letters = "bean"`.

Answer (score 2):

Where you have

```
letters = ["bean"]
```

that sets `letters` to a list. That's what the `[ ]` mean.

You iterate `letter` through the list, so `letter` gets set to the element inside the list, i.e. the word `"bean"`.

Then you try and call `ord` on the string `"bean"`, which does not work because it's more than a single character.

If instead you have

```
letters = "bean"
```

then `letters` indicates the string itself, not a list; and when you iterate through the string, `letter` will be set to each character in turn, so calling `ord` will work.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your advice fixed it!